# Asymptotic for $\int_0^1 z e^{-\frac{(d+z)^2}{a}} \text d z$ for $a\to 0$.

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Actually, for a small $d\in (0,1)$, I am interested in the asymptotic for 
$$\int_0^1 z e^{-\frac{(d+z)^2}{a}} \text d z$$
as $a\to 0$. To simplify this a bit I wanted to look at the upper bound
$$\int_0^1 e^{-\frac{(d+z)^2}{a}} \text d z,$$
which decreases faster than $e^{-\frac{d^2} a}$ and slower than $e^{-\frac{(d+\varepsilon)^2} a}$ for any $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$.

Is there a "closed form" of the asymptotic behaviour of those integrals?

I did not try to calculate the integral value, because the actual integral involves the additional factor $1/(d+z)^2$ under integration.

Comment: I think we should use a variable other than $d$ here, since it can get confusing. Aside from that, your first integral can actually be written in terms of the second, whose value has no closed form except in terms of the error function. (That does not preclude asymptotic analysis. I don't know about that.)

Comment: How can I write the first in terms of the second?

Comment: Write $z$ = $d + z - d$ and break up the integral into two terms. You should get the second integral with a coefficient of $-d$, while the other term can be evaluated by making the substitution $u = -(d + z)^2 / a$ and simplifying a bit.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \int_0^1 z e^{-(d+z)^2/a} dz\sim e^{-d^2/a}\left( \frac{a^2}{4d^2} - \frac{3a^3}{8d^4} + \frac{15a^4}{16d^6} + \sum_{s=3}^\infty c_s \, (s+1)! \,a^{s+2}\right).$$

Apply [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). (See II.Theorem 1 in Asymptotic Approximations Of Integrals by R. Wong; the proof is based on [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).)

Comment: There is a mistake somewhere in your calculations. Expanding around zero gives
$$\int_0^\infty z e^{-(d^2 + 2 d z)/a} \mathrm dz =
\frac {a^2} {4 d^2} e^{-d^2/a}$$
for the leading term.

Comment: Yah, maybe still faulty..

Comment: Looks good now. Making a change of variables to bring the integrand into the form $f(u) e^{-u/a}$, expanding $f(u)$ around zero and integrating, I got the same three terms.